# In R, find all the rows that cause an error and print as list

Tags: r, error-handling

I have some simple code that separates different rows by a ";" and which generates an error and stops the code. I'd like to list those rows and remove them into another dataframe "DF" if possible. However, I am unable to generate a code to make the list. I have tried tryCatch and it freezes.

The code is;

```
DT <- DT %>%
  separate_rows(Col1,Col2,  sep = '; ')
```

An example of a row that would cause an error would be;

row1 <- c("1;2", "1;2;3") because they do not have equal ";"

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you provide a few lines of your DT object using `dput(DT[1:5])` or `dput(DT[1:5,])` (if it's a dataframe). Also, are your rows with > 1 delimiters actually erroneous data? Or is it that you don't know how to process rows with uneven delimiter lengths? If it's the latter, simply use the `splitstackshape` package and this code: `cSplit(DT, c("col1", "col2"), ";", type.convert = "as.character")`. The function `cSplit()` will add NAs where there are uneven delimiter lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of waiting for the errors to occur, I would rather identify the rows that will cause an error by a logic.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

(tbl <- tibble(x = c("1;2", "1;2;3", "1;3"),
               y = c("1;2", "1;3", "1;2;3")))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   x     y    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1;2   1;2  
#> 2 1;2;3 1;3  
#> 3 1;3   1;2;3

# first error in row 2
tbl |> tidyr::separate_rows(x, y, sep = ";")
#> Error in `tidyr::separate_rows()`:
#> ! In row 2, can't recycle input of size 3 to size 2.

# define separator
sep <- ";"
# define variables
cols <- c("x", "y")

# count separators in each row and flag those that have nonunique occurrences
causes_error <- apply(X = tbl |> select(all_of(cols)),
                      MARGIN = 1,
                      FUN = function(x) {
                        num_semicolons <- stringi::stri_count(x, fixed = sep)
                        length(unique(num_semicolons)) != 1
                      })

tbl |> 
  dplyr::filter(causes_error)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   x     y    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1;2;3 1;3  
#> 2 1;3   1;2;3
```

Comment: Why not just fill with NA?? the data is perfectly fine. I do not see any that would cause errors. Its just that you should use another function instead of `separate_rows`

Answer (score 1):

To find rows with unequal `;`:

```
a <- nchar(gsub("[^;]", "", as.matrix(tbl)))
subset(tbl, a[,1]! = a[,2])

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 1;2;3 1;3  
2 1;3   1;2;3
```

But that should not be an error. Your error is because you are trying to use `separate_rows` but you should use different functions:

You could write a generalized Base R function: -- ie using base R as they are readily available:

```
my_separate_rows <- function(dat, ..., sep = '', drop = TRUE){
    cols <- as.character(substitute(...()))
    fn <- function(x, y){
         df1 <- read.table(text=x, fill = TRUE, header = FALSE, sep=sep)    
         setNames(stack(na.omit(unlist(df1))), c(y, ".ind"))
    }
    d <- Reduce(\(x,y)merge(x,y,all = TRUE), Map(fn, dat[cols], cols))
    d1 <- cbind(.ind = seq(nrow(dat)),if(drop)dat[!names(dat) %in% cols] else dat)
    e <- merge(d1, transform(d, .ind = substr(.ind,3,3),.ind1=.ind), 
                         by = '.ind', suffixes = c('_original', ''))
    subset(e[order(e$.ind, e$.ind1),], select = -c(.ind,.ind1))
}
```

---

Now lets try to use the function in the table below:

```
tbl
      x     y       z
1   1;2   1;2     1;4
2 1;2;3   1;3 1;2;3;4
3   1;3 1;2;3       1
```

---

```
my_separate_rows(tbl,x, sep=';')
      y       z x
1   1;2     1;4 1
2   1;2     1;4 2
3   1;3 1;2;3;4 1
4   1;3 1;2;3;4 2
5   1;3 1;2;3;4 3
6 1;2;3       1 1
7 1;2;3       1 3
my_separate_rows(tbl,x, z, sep=';', drop = FALSE)
  x_original     y z_original  x  z
1        1;2   1;2        1;4  1  1
2        1;2   1;2        1;4  2  4
3      1;2;3   1;3    1;2;3;4  1  1
4      1;2;3   1;3    1;2;3;4  2  2
5      1;2;3   1;3    1;2;3;4  3  3
6      1;2;3   1;3    1;2;3;4 NA  4
7        1;3 1;2;3          1  1  1
8        1;3 1;2;3          1  3 NA
> my_separate_rows(tbl,x,y, z, sep=';', drop = FALSE)
  x_original y_original z_original  x  y  z
1        1;2        1;2        1;4  1  1  1
2        1;2        1;2        1;4  2  2  4
3      1;2;3        1;3    1;2;3;4  1  1  1
5      1;2;3        1;3    1;2;3;4  2  3  2
4      1;2;3        1;3    1;2;3;4  3 NA  3
6      1;2;3        1;3    1;2;3;4 NA NA  4
8        1;3      1;2;3          1  1  1  1
7        1;3      1;2;3          1  3  2 NA
9        1;3      1;2;3          1 NA  3 NA
```